# Two variable function continuous except of the points on the diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I would like to find a function $f(x,y)$ for $x,y \in (0,1) $ such that it is continuous everywhere except of the points for which $x=y$ (in those points it is discontinuous), but $x \to f(x,x)$ as a function of one variable is continuous.

I have come up with

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x=y \\ 0 & x \neq y \end{cases} $$

It is definitely continuous for points $x \neq y$ and $x \to f(x,x)$ is also continuous, however, I am not sure whether it is discontinuous in points on the *diagonal*.

I would appreciate your help solving this problem.

Comment: Your function satisfies all the conditions stated. To check the discontinuity, I suggest you use the sequential characterisation of continuity with a sequence in $\{x\neq y\}$ that converges to a point $(x,x)$.

Comment: Let $I = (0,1)\times (0,1)$ and further let $\ell =\{(x,y)\in I:x=y\}$ and $U=I\backslash \ell$. If $\mathbf{x} \in \ell$ then if $f$ were continuous at $\mathbf{x}$ you would be able to find a ball $B(\mathbf{x},\delta)$ whose elements $\mathbf{y}$ are all such that $\|f(\mathbf{y})-f(\mathbf{x})\| < 1/2$. But any such ball contains some  $\mathbf{y} \in U$, for which we will have $\| f(\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{x})\| = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is discontinuous at those points. If $a\in(0,1)$ and $\delta>0$, take $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap(0,1)$, with $x\ne a$. Then $\|(x,a)-(a,a)\|<\delta$. But $\bigl|f(x,a)-f(a,a)\bigr|=1$. So, this proves that, for every $\delta>0$, there is some $(x,y)\in(0,1)^2$ such that $\|(x,y)-(a,a)\|<\delta$ and that $\bigl|f(x,a)-f(a,a)\bigr|\geqslant1$. So, by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, $f$ is discontinuous at $(a,a)$.